# Having issues running multiple stage inside a try block in a jenkins script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-cli

I am new to jenkins and groovy and is unable to figure out an issue with a Jenkins scripts, it would be great if I can get some help/feedback regarding this matter as to how to debug the issue. So the issue is that jenkins is not marking build fail( red and shows them as green) but when you open the logs for those jobs you can clearly see that the build failed as there are compiler issues. The builds in question are `Windows Build` and `Windows Unit Tests`. As far as I can tell the two main scripts are `PipelineUtils.groovy` which is something like this

```
def build_and_test_windows(fail_build_on_test) {
    boolean run_tests = true
    build_windows(run_tests, fail_build_on_test)
}

def get_results_on_failure(failBuildOnFailure) {
String buildResult = failBuildOnFailure ? "FAILURE" : "SUCCESS"
String stageResult = failBuildOnFailure ? "FAILURE" : "UNSTABLE"

return [buildResult, stageResult]
}

def build_windows(run_tests, fail_build_on_test) {
    String buildResult
    String stageResult
    (buildResult, stageResult) = get_results_on_failure(fail_build_on_test)
node("windows"){
      setupWorkspace()
    try{
      stage('Windows Build') {
        timeout(time: 60, unit: 'MINUTES') {
          bat "${JENKINS_TOOLS_DIR}/platform-specific/windows/windows.bat"
        }
      }
      if (run_tests) {
        stage('Windows Unit Tests') {
          catchError(buildResult: buildResult, stageResult: stageResult) {
            timeout(time: 60, unit: 'MINUTES') {
              bat "${JENKINS_TOOLS_DIR}/platform-specific/windows/windows.bat TRUE"
            }
          }
        }
      } 
    }finally{
        cleanWorkspace()
      }
```

and the invoking script which is something like this

```
boolean MANDATORY_TESTS = true
...
...
try{

...

parallel 

'Windows' : {
        pipeline_utils.build_and_test_windows(MANDATORY_STAGE)
...
...

completed = true
}catch(Exception error){
    currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
    pipeline_utils.notifyPipelineFailed(currentBuild)
    pipeline_utils.reportBuildResultToCloudwatch("1")
    throw(error)
} finally {
    if (completed && currentBuild.result != 'FAILURE') {
        pipeline_utils.upload_stable_sdk()
        def emailList = SUCCESS_EMAIL_LIST ?: ""
        pipeline_utils.notifyPipelineSuccess(currentBuild, emailList);
        pipeline_utils.reportBuildResultToCloudwatch("0")
    }
}
```

Now windows.bat file is failing in both instances and there are compiler issues and its last line is

```
make: *** [Makefile:161: all] Error 2
```

Now currently even if the bat script is failing I am seeing both stage jobs showing as green on jenkins, I tried adding catchError to the Windows Build stage as well something like this

```
node("windows"){
  setupWorkspace()
  try{
    stage('Windows Build') {
      catchError(buildResult: buildResult, stageResult: stageResult) {
       timeout(time: 60, unit: 'MINUTES') {
         bat "${JENKINS_TOOLS_DIR}/platform-specific/windows/windows.bat"
       }
      }
    }
    if (run_tests) {
      stage('Windows Unit Tests') {
        catchError(buildResult: buildResult, stageResult: stageResult) {
          timeout(time: 60, unit: 'MINUTES') {
            bat "${JENKINS_TOOLS_DIR}/platform-specific/windows/windows.bat TRUE"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }finally{
    cleanWorkspace()
  }
```

But now the `windows build stage job` fails on Jenkins and is red but the `'Windows Unit Tests'` is still showing green even though logs indicate that it should fail due to compile issues.

Would be great if someone can help me understand what is going on and how to debug /fix the script, basically trying to fix the script such that both jobs fail if the bat script have errors.

Answer (score 0):

The [catchError](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#catcherror-catch-error-and-set-build-result-to-failure) step doesn't stop the build on failure. It means that all code bellow it is executed no matter what was the result of the action executed inside it. Example:

```
stage('1') {
  catchError {
    error 'fail build'
  }
}
stage('2') { // this stage is executed
  echo 'stage 2'
}
stage('3') { // this stage is also executed
  echo 'stage 3'
}
```

The `build_and_test_windows` method is executed in the `try-finally` block. The simplest option is to not use the `catcheError` step at all. When `Windows Build` fails the whole build should fail. It is given OOTB:

```
stage('Windows Build') {
  timeout(time: 60, unit: 'MINUTES') {
    bat "${JENKINS_TOOLS_DIR}/platform-specific/windows/windows.bat"
  }
}
```

The tests you may mark as unstable by using the [unstable](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#unstable-set-stage-result-to-unstable) step:

```
stage('Windows Unit Tests') {
  timeout(time: 60, unit: 'MINUTES') {
    try {
      bat "${JENKINS_TOOLS_DIR}/platform-specific/windows/windows.bat TRUE"
    } catch(e) {
      unstable "Tests have failed"
    }
  }
}
```

However when you mark tests as unstable, the logic from your `catch` won't be executed:

```
} catch (Exception error){
  currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
  pipeline_utils.notifyPipelineFailed(currentBuild)
  pipeline_utils.reportBuildResultToCloudwatch("1")
  throw(error)
} finally {
```

If you have to notify about the unstable tests too, then I don't think marking the stage as yellow instead of red is worth to introduce a lot of hacks. The code without any additional logic does what you need:

```
stage('Windows Unit Tests') {
  timeout(time: 60, unit: 'MINUTES') {
    bat "${JENKINS_TOOLS_DIR}/platform-specific/windows/windows.bat TRUE"
  }
}
```